# Bitnami GitLab (ubuntu) server can't get time synchronized

Tags: ubuntu, time, synchronization, gitlab, bitnami

I am using [BitNami GitLab Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine) [5.2.0](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/README.txt) running in VirutalBox.

The server time got back, but I can't use standard Ubuntu recommendations: 
[Time Synchronization with NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html).

It all shows errors.

Is there alternative or Bitnami special way?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure for your version but the following works for [BitNami LAMPStack](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/virtual-machine) 5.3.15-0 (and for every other LAMPStack version I presume).

```
sudo aptitude install ntp
```

However, it is possible the errors you mention are due to the virtual machine inheriting the clock from the hardware it is hosted on. I you keep getting errors, I would take a look on how to solve the problem from the VirtualBox side, [something like this](http://nerdboys.com/2011/03/15/how-to-fix-virtualbox-time-synchonization-problems/) might help.